# Google Chrome, audio, setTimeout, replace audio src, restarts mid-audio

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, settimeout, html5-audio, src

This is only an issue in Chrome and runs fine in the other browsers.

I click a speaker which plays a welcome message, if the welcome message is not finished, I keep checking until it is finished, then I change the source to another message.

If I then click the speaker again to hear the new message, this message starts and after a few seconds stops and starts again, then stops (my estimate is that it stops when the duration of that message is passed)

In my html:

```
<audio id="shop_audio" preload="auto" type="audio/mpeg" src="/audios/helper/shop/en/welcome.mp3"></audio>
<p id="shop_speaker">
    <i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
</p>
```

In my javascript:

Doc ready:

```
$("#shop_speaker").click(function(){
    document.getElementById("shop_audio").play();
});
```

Then:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    sl.utils.t_shopInstructions = setTimeout(sl.shop.audio.setAudio, 5000, 0);
});
```

And:

```
sl.shop.audio={
    setAudio: function(which){
        clearTimeout(sl.utils.t_shopInstructions);
        var audio = document.getElementById("shop_audio");
        if(audio.paused==true){
            sl.shop.audio.newSrc(which);
        }else{
            sl.utils.t_shopAudioPlaying = setInterval(sl.shop.audio.waitForPaused, 500, which);
        }
    },
    waitForPaused: function(which){
        if(document.getElementById("shop_audio").paused==true){
            clearInterval(sl.utils.t_shopAudioPlaying);
            sl.shop.audio.newSrc(which);
        }
    },
    newSrc: function(which){
        document.getElementById("shop_audio").src = '/audios/helper/shop/en/help_instruction_'+which+'.mp3';
    }
}
```

And a variant that also works everywhere, except chrome:
(I thought that setInterval was causing trouble, and/or its clearing)

```
sl.shop.audio={
    setAudio: function(which){
        clearTimeout(sl.utils.t_shopInstructions);
        var audio = document.getElementById("shop_audio");
        if(audio.paused==true){
            sl.shop.audio.newSrc(which);
        }else{
            (function looping(){
                clearTimeout(sl.utils.t_shopAudioPlaying);
                if(audio.paused==false){
                    sl.utils.t_shopAudioPlaying=setTimeout(looping, 500);
                }else{
                    sl.shop.audio.newSrc(which);
                }
            })()
        }
    },
    newSrc: function(which){
        document.getElementById("shop_audio").src = '/audios/helper/shop/en/help_instruction_'+which+'.mp3';
    }
}
```

Placing the `clearTimeout()` in different places makes a difference, so I pursued that, but the result is not consistent.

I have now removed all the clearTimeouts - they make no difference whatsoever. The problem stays exactly the same.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

> I click a speaker which plays a welcome message, if the welcome
>   message is not finished, I keep checking until it is finished, then I
>   change the source to another message.

You can substitute `ended` event for `setTimeout`. Since you are using jQuery use `.one()` instead of `.click()`.

```
var audio = $("#shop_audio")[0];
var speaker = $("#shop_speaker");

function resetAudio() {
    audio.play();
    audio.onended = function() {
      this.onended = null;
      this.src = "/path/to/a/different/src";
      speaker.one("click", resetAudio);
    }
}

speaker.one("click", resetAudio);
```

Comment: I like the looks of your code! Much more elegant. Only problem is that the problem is not going away, but now also the first message gets aborted, restarts and then dies. (in Google Chrome only! Fine everywhere else!!)

Comment: @Daniela Can you create a plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate? Are you trying to change `src` of `audio` only when audio has finished playing?

Comment: yes, of course. thing is the other browsers have no problem, only Chrome.

Comment: @Daniela What is expected result?

Comment: ok. I have added it in js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pcLL383c/12/  It works great, also in Chrome. I have now replaced the src of the audio with the external address, so loading from server. It works. In this case it must be something to do with how Chrome caches??

Comment: @Daniela _"It works great, also in Chrome. I have now replaced the src of the audio with the external address, so loading from server. It works. In this case it must be something to do with how Chrome caches??"_ Not sure what you mean by "In this case"? Does `javascript` at Answer resolve Question?

Comment: not really.
if first audio never gets clicked/played, speaker still needs to move on to second audio, so onended not right choice in this case.
you did help me isolate the problem though - it was not in the code, but has something to do with the browser and how it caches the audio, since problem does not arise if I load audio from a different source.

Comment: What do you mean by _"if first audio never gets clicked/played, speaker still needs to move on to second audio"_ ? At original Question you describe playing the audio only when "a speaker" is clicked _"I click a speaker which plays a welcome message"_

Comment: yes. if the speaker gets clicked (within 5 secs), the first audio needs to be played and the loading of the second audio needs to wait until it has finished playing. If the speaker does not get clicked for 5 secs, the second audio needs to load, so when the speaker gets clicked later, that is what gets played.